# How to debug code in dynamic libraries called from Java on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, debugging, java-native-interface

Our application consists of a part written in Java and a part written in C++. The Java part is the main application, while the C++ part gets compiled into dynamic libraries for the respective platform and then accessed through the JNI.

Debugging on Windows is nice and easy:

1. Compile the dynamic libraries with debug symbols.
2. Open the corresponding C++ source file(s) in Visual Studio, no project needed.
3. Start the Java application.
4. Attach Visual Studio debugger to the corresponding `javaw` process.
5. Set a breakpoint in the previously opened C++ source file and start debugging as soon as the breakpoint is hit by the application.

Is there a similar workflow possible on OSX?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is a little more project focused, so you have to make a project to do anything, and the source files need to be part of the project, but they don't need to build into anything.  So just make a MacOS xcode project using the command-line template. Do `File->Add Files to MyProject` and select the folder containing your sources.  You can add them to the Project's target or not - it doesn't really matter, since you aren't using the project to build anything.  Then set breakpoints in those source files, run your Java Application and do `Debug->Attach to Process by PID or Name` and type in your process name.